# Get file path dynamically to import into React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I have a React app written in Javascript. I am importing a minified js file from a specific location but I want to get that file path dynamically so other users can run the app *locally* and specify a different path for the file. (This app is not being used for production, only for testing locally and some developers have the minified file in a different directory that I do.)

Right now I'm getting the file path as follows

```
import { minified_file } from '../../path/minified_file_name.min.js';

const MyComponent =  () => {
    const settings = {...};
    const min = minified_file(settings);
    
    ...
  

    return (
        <>
            <div> {min} </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I would like to get the file in a way like

`import { minified_file } from config.minifiedFilePath;`

or something.

I tried adding the file path to my development.json and pulling the file path from there but that requires me to require config in my javascript function.

I've tried to look up if I can pass the file path via npm start but I have yet to make headway with that search.

Is there a way I can set up my React app to accept different file paths either from a development.json or npm start or something?

Comment: What is your build system? Vite? Webpack?

Comment: We're using webpack